# How to send an event to another views

Tags: ember.js

As the answer on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642077/accessing-other-controller-from-a-view) I learned that binding between two controller is kind of a bad design. I tried to solve it with event handling.

```
App.TestView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({     
 tagName:'tbody',
 contentBinding: 'this.controller.content',
 itemViewClass: Em.View.extend({
   templateName:'test',
   classNameBindings:['selected:selected'],
   selectedBinding: 'content.selected',
   click: function(event){
     var controller =  this.get('controller');
     this.resetSelection(); 
     this.content.set('selected',true);
     router = this.get('controller.target.router');  
     router.transitionTo('inc.index',this.content);
     // just sends it to the parentView
     controller.send('noHide',false);
   }
 })
});
App.MainMenuView = Em.View.extend({
 noHide: function(event){
 this.get('controller').set('isHidden',false);
 }
})
```

But now I don't know how to send events to other views or other routes that are not a parent view. I just want to toggle a hidden menu item when I click on a row of my table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Ember.Instrumentation` to call into any controller from anywhere else.

First subscribe to an event in `setupController`, you can choose whichever name you want for the event and call your desired function in the before handler. The payload is optional.

```
App.MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    Ember.Instrumentation.subscribe("app.myEventName", {
      before: function (name, timestamp, payload) {
       controller.send('functionToCall', payload);
      },
      after: function () { }
    });
  }
});
```

When you want to call the function, you do the following

```
Ember.Instrumentation.instrument('app.myEventName', myPayload);
```

You can read more here http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Instrumentation.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured it out myself. Here is the solution:

```
App.TableController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
 needs: ['mainMenu'],
 hidden:true,
 hiddenBinding: 'controllers.mainMenu.isHidden', 
  noHide: function(test){
    this.get('controllers.mainMenu').changeHidden(test);
 }
 })
App.MainMenuController= Em.Controller.extend({
 isHidden: true,
 changeHidden: function(test){
 this.set('isHidden',test)
 }
 });
```

The event is delegated to controller of the parentView. From there i got the link to my     mainMenuController via 'needs' to call the changeHidden function.